# How to use multiple random strings in Python / Pyramid?

Tags: python, string, random, pyramid

So I have this definition which basically just saves a user's profile.
Currently I have 1 success message, I would like to rotate between multiple success and error messages the:
 `value = {'result': 'success', 'message': '...'}`

How would you go about this?

```
@view_config(route_name="profile", request_method='POST')
def save_profile(self):
    try:
        json = self.request.json_body
        first_name = str(json['firstName'])
        last_name = str(json['lastName'])
        organization = str(json['organization'])
        title = str(json['title'])
        phones = (json['phones'])
        emails = (json['emails'])
        self.profiles.update(firstName=first_name, lastName=last_name, organization=organization, title=title, emails=emails, phones=phones)
        value = {'result': 'success', 'message': "Saved! Worry not, nothing sent to the NSA... as far as we know"}
    except Exception, err:
        print err
        value = {'result': 'error', 'message': 'The internets are clogged up, our monkeys are checking it out'}
```

Comment: How about sticking the messages in a list and then selecting randomly from that list? Also you don't need parenthesis around `(json['phones'])` and similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a list of success/error messages:

```
import random
errors = ['dog ate it', 'flying monkeys stole it', 'rabbits attacked it']
value = {'result': 'error', 'message': random.choice(errors)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put your messages in an array (instead of a dictionary) and then let a random index choose one for you:

```
random.randint(1,*max_number*)
```